# FBAudienceNetwork adapter makes build errors by objc flag in settings

Tags: ios, facebook, admob

I use Admob's Mediation.

Currently added FAN. Messages following is shown.

```
"<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): GADMAdapterFacebook. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target."
```

And add -Objc in Settings, Build error like the below...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "vtable for std::out_of_range", referenced from:

      FNFCursor::readBE16(unsigned long long) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFCursor.o)

      FNFCursor::readBE32(unsigned long long) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFCursor.o)

      FNFCursor::readBE64(unsigned long long) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFCursor.o)

      FNFCursor::read8(unsigned long long) in FBAudienceNetwork(FNFCursor.o)

  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.



......
```

FAN is supporting Bitcode. But FAN Adapter is not support, yet.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I first add -force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/Facebook/libAdapterFacebook.a and bitcode enalbed turned off.  and Plus I added the framework libc++.tbd in build phases tab. I solved by this methods.

Comment: Also add "-lxml2" to "other linker flags"